# Android MediaPlayer unwilling to seek through RTSP video stream

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, android-mediaplayer

I am designing a custom streaming video player that can stream videos over HTTP as well as RTSP, and am currently developing for the Lenovo IdeaPad A1 (Android 2.3.4).  I am experiencing issues with the MediaPlayer while trying to seek within a video that is streaming over RTSP, using the "Direct RTSP URL" from [Wowza's website](http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html).  The video streams and plays just fine, but something within the framework is reporting that this is a live stream, and it simply ignores my use of the MediaPlayer's seekTo function.

```
03-19 10:51:08.156: W/MyHandler(1062): This is a live stream, ignoring seek request.
03-19 10:51:08.156: I/MyHandler(1062): seek done
03-19 10:51:08.195: D/VideoStream(1523): onSeekComplete
03-19 10:51:08.218: D/Omap3ALSA(1062): open called for devices 00000002 in mode 0 channels 00000000...
03-19 10:51:08.250: W/InputManagerService(1135): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407e5230
03-19 10:51:08.257: I/Omap3ALSA(1062): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device default
03-19 10:51:08.257: E/AudioHardwareALSA(1062): RE-OPEN AFTER STANDBY:: took 33 msecs
```

It makes sense that a live stream cannot be "seeked," but this particular video is a fixed-length video file.  I have also been working with an HTC Flyer, but I do not experience this issue the Flyer because it does not characterize the stream as a "live stream," which is correct.  I am able to stream the same video and seek with no problems.  The Flyer is using Android 2.3.3 and has HTC Sense.  Both devices seem to use Stagefright for the media framework, as opposed to OpenCore.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this (even on other devices), and if so, did you find a way around it?  It's frustrating that the code works flawlessly on one device but not on the other.  Additionally, does anyone know of any other RTSP streams available online for testing?  (Youtube's mobile site seems to be a bit flighty, even on the Flyer.)

Comment: Having the exact same problem on Samsung Nexus S. Android 2.3.6. Completely unable to seek on an RTSP video stream from a wowza media server with a fixed length video. Hopefully someone out there has this working.

Comment: @Dave Dang, I'm sorry to hear you're having the same problem.  Our project requirements changed, and this became a lower priority, so unfortunately, I never found a real resolution to it.